# Visual Studio 2010 Mismatch Detected _MSC_VER Value doesn't match

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, directx

I'm getting the following error when trying to setup Directx11 in VS2010 on Windows 7. What is causing this? I have all my directories and linker files setup, and I keep running into this problem.

Thanks.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyD3D11Project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 22-May-13 4:35:22 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\MyD3D11Project.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectAPI.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in d3dApp.obj
1>Effects11d.lib(d3dxGlobal.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in d3dApp.obj
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectNonRuntime.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in d3dApp.obj
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectLoad.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in d3dApp.obj
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectReflection.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in d3dApp.obj
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectRuntime.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1600' in d3dApp.obj
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.16
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you try *Rebuild All*? It seems *d3dApp.cpp* (or *.c*) was built with a different version of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Praetorian I clicked rebuild solution and it produces the same errors.

Comment: @Praetorian $1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt$ this is now the only error I have!

Answer (score 0):

Like the name of the Lib already says, it's most likely built for VS12 note the "11d" in the Library name (Or I am wrong and it stands for DirectX11, I am not sure, as I've never used DirectX...).

So try linking against a VS10 Version (should contain "10" instead of 11 in the name).

About the coff error, I think it can be fixed by installing the latest service packs for VS10.